# Quantum algorithms for generalizations of determinants

Tags: quantum-computing, cr.crypto-security, permanent

There are a wide variety of determent-like constructions.  Some like the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent) or immanents are variations on the ordinary determinant for matrices over fields or commutative rings. Some like [quasideterminants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasideterminant) extend the theory of determinants to non-commutative rings.

At least permanents have a [rich](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16471/lower-bound-for-determinant-and-permanent) complexity theory, perhaps the others do to.

For any of these constructions, is there a quantum algorithm that asymptotically out preforms the fastest classical algorithms for computing it?

I'm asking because some post-quantum crypto systems like http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1270 and code-based crypto suffer from extremely large key sizes due to representing public keys as matrices.  A priori, it might be possible to "compress" that large matrix into something like a characteristic polynomial but using some non-commutative analog of the determinant.  This approach sounds less viable if quantum computers could compute some analogs of the determinant more quickly.

Comment: Quantum data compression can allow one to have 3 qubits to be compressed to 2 qubits. Even so, due to the error rates, these quantum error data compression schemes unreliable. The error in such data compression make it unreliable as a data compression scheme as quantum data compression does not do a frequency count of 0's and 1's, but current quantum data compression measure oneness, or zeroness, of a qubit. So, if a quantum computer would be used to  compress a matrix- it would compress with a high error. Scaling the quantum data compression is still not feasible currently.

Comment: I'm asking about quantum algorithms for computing analogs of the determent.  I used the word "compress" to fallaciously to refer to homomorphic properties of some analogs of the determent.  A determent is an invariant of a matrix though, not a way to compress a matrix.